# Firebase Pushnotification - Send a link as part of the notification and when the user clicks on that open a link

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to a user using firebase and when a user click on the notification, it should open a link. The requirement is for PWA App
When i checked the documentation there are 2 options,

1. using webpush
   `"webpush": { "fcm_options": { "link": "google.com" }`
2. using data
    `"data": { "url": "google.com" }`

in either case i need to write a handler for the click action on the UI side. If that is the case i can use data all the time. why i need to use webpush?

Can someone clarify should i use webpush or data for my requirement...

i tried both the cases and both worked... but which one is the right approach